# Using multiple Ransack search forms in one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm using several search_form_for on one page and I'm having a problem with the passed parameters. When one of the forms is submitted, its parameters override the parameters of other forms.

For example, need this on submit:

```
Parameters: {"q"=>{"search_cont"=>"qwerty", "by_discarded"=>"discarded"}, "f"=>{"search_cont"=>"asdfgh", "by_discarded"=>"active"}}
```

but getting it

```
Parameters: {"q"=>{"search_cont"=>"qwerty", "by_discarded"=>"discarded"}}
```

or it

```
Parameters: {"f"=>{"search_cont"=>"asdfgh", "by_discarded"=>"active"}}
```

---

*View*:

```
    <%= search_form_for @q, url: url, as: :q do |f| %>
          <%= f.search_field :search_cont, value: params.dig(:q, :search_cont), placeholder: 'Search' %>
          <%= f.select(:by_discarded, [['Active', 'active'], ['Discarded', 'discarded']], { selected: params.dig(:q, :by_discarded) }, { onchange: 'this.form.submit();' }) %>
    <% end %>
    ...
    <%= search_form_for @f, url: url, as: :f do |f| %>
          <%= f.search_field :search_cont, value: params.dig(:f, :search_cont), placeholder: 'Search' %>
          <%= f.select(:by_discarded, [['Active', 'active'], ['Discarded', 'discarded']], { selected: params.dig(:f, :by_discarded) }, { onchange: 'this.form.submit();' }) %>
    <% end %>
```

*Controller*:

```
@q = some_items.ransack(params[:q])
@q.sorts = 'sort_order asc' if @q.sorts.empty?
@pagy_q, @objects_q = pagy(@q.result, page_param: :page_q)

@f = another_items.ransack(params[:f], search_key: :f)
@f.sorts = 'sort_order asc' if @f.sorts.empty?
@pagy_f, @objects_f = pagy(@f.result, page_param: :page_f)
```

How to pass parameters from all forms when submitting one of the forms?

Comment: You can catch submit event in JS and merge values of other form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. using **js** catching the submit event and then uniting the parameters of both forms
2. **unite both forms in one**, but visually divide them into two. When you submit form you will be able to get parameters only from the form you submitted.